# Double Quoted variables failing the script

Tags: shell, glob

I am having trouble while using quoted variables to call a script within a script.

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts c:a: optionalargs
do
        case $optionalargs in
          c)copt=$OPTARG;;
          a)aopt=$OPTARG;;
          *)echo "Invalid arg";;
        esac
done

if [ ! -z "$copt" ]
then
    export CHAR_SET=$copt
fi

if [ ! -z "$aopt" ]
then
    export ADDITIONAL_FLAGS=$aopt
fi

shift $((OPTIND -1))

/var/bin/script1.sh "${CHAR_SET}" "${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}"
```

**Results:**

when using `/var/bin/script1.sh "${CHAR_SET}" "${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}"` with quotes

```
./a.sh -a additional -c character
too many arguments . Use -h for help
```

when using `/var/bin/script1.sh ${CHAR_SET} ${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}` without quotes

```
./a.sh -a additional -c character
script runs fine
```

**Question:**

Why the double quotes failing my script? Shouldn't it prevent globbing?

Comment: Change shebang line to `#!/bin/sh -x` and see what debug output you get.

Comment: it gave me `./a.sh -a 'additional' -c 'character'` For the sake of a minimal example I have 2 parameters but in reality it is 7.

Comment: Please show an example of calling your main script with arguments that DO work and also with arguments that don't work. I can't get the error messages you specify use `./code.sh  -a additional -c "character extra"` for example. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter Just with the same arguments I came up with this just by changing the quoted argument at the last line of my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was identified in the script that is being called internally. It processes the double-quoted arguments and replaces with single quotes. So, this is really not an issue.